# Javascript: Save image from <canvas /> as png file and preserve canvas opacity

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, png, opacity

I use the following code to save canvas content as png image file to server storage:

```
canvasEl.toBlob(blob => {
    const file = new File([blob], fileName);
    onImageUpload(file, fileName);
});
```

and it works fine. canvas also has opacity settings set using CSS { opacity: value }. What I need is to save PNG file with same opacity as canvas has through CSS property opacity. How can I do it on web browser side?

Comment: Change `onImageUpload` to pass the opacity value to the server.

Comment: You can draw the canvas to itself. Setting the alpha value you want. Steps as follows `const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")` get 2D API, `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "copy"` ensures old pixels are removed, `ctx.globalAlpha = myAlphaValue;` set the alpha value you want to apply to all pixels, `ctx.drawImage(canvasEl, 0, 0)` draw canvas onto itself.  And then send the PNG to server `canvasEl.toBlob(blob => {.../*etc*/`